# Set maximum time for preloader

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, time, preloader

Does anyone know of a way to set a maximum time that a preloader can display?  In the event that someone has a slow connection, it would be useful to make the preloader disappear after a few seconds so it does not show forever.
Here is the code I am currently using for the preloader.

```js
    // makes sure the whole site is loaded
    jQuery(window).load(function () {
        "use strict";
        // will first fade out the loading animation
        if(  jQuery( '.et-bfb' ).length <= 0 && jQuery( '.et-fb' ).length <= 0  ){ 
            jQuery(".status").fadeOut();
            // will fade out the whole DIV that covers the website.
            jQuery(".preloader").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");
        }else{
            jQuery(".preloader").css('display','none');
        }
    });
```

```css
.preloader {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: #fefefe;
   z-index: 100000;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden !important;
}

.preloader .status {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   background-image: url(http://monticellomansion.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/dbf29347459a27eb6736f2164539440e.gif);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preloader">
<div class="status"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you saw my answer ?

Comment: @SKJ Yes I do see the answer now, see my reply to that answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You rather just use $(document).ready

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Because : *The load() method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.8 and removed in version 3.0.* https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_load.asp

Instead of using > ***jQuery( '.et-bfb' )***, You can use "**$**".

```js
// makes sure the whole site is loaded
$(document).ready(function() {
  // will first fade out the loading animation
  if ($( '.et-bfb' ).length <= 0 && $( '.et-fb' ).length <= 0) { 
    $(".status").fadeOut();
    // will fade out the whole DIV that covers the website.
    $(".preloader").delay(1000).fadeOut("slow");
  } else {
    $(".preloader").css('display','none');
  }
});
```

```css
.preloader {
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   bottom: 0;
   background-color: #fefefe;
   z-index: 100000;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden !important;
}

.preloader .status {
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
   position: absolute;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   background-image: url(http://monticellomansion.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/dbf29347459a27eb6736f2164539440e.gif);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-position: center;
   -webkit-background-size: cover;
   background-size: cover;
   margin: -50px 0 0 -50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preloader">
  <div class="status"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I tried using your updated code for the script, it does not work.  The preloaded displays forever and does not disappear.  Changed back to old code and it works fine.  Regardless, it does not answer my question.  I would like to set a maximum time the preloader appears before it dissapears (regardless of whether the page is loaded).  Do you know of a way to do this?  Thanks.